# Getting all new messages from a Maildir in python

Tags: python, maildir

I have a mail dir:

```
foo@foo:~/Maildir$ ls -l
total 288
drwx------ 2 foo foo 155648 2010-04-19 15:19 cur
-rw------- 1 foo foo    440 2010-03-20 08:50 dovecot.index.log
-rw------- 1 foo foo    112 2010-03-20 08:49 dovecot-uidlist
-rw------- 1 foo foo      8 2010-03-20 08:49 dovecot-uidvalidity
-rw------- 1 foo foo      0 2010-03-20 08:49 dovecot-uidvalidity.4ba48c0e
drwx------ 2 foo foo 114688 2010-04-19 16:07 new
drwx------ 2 foo foo   4096 2010-04-19 16:07 tmp
```

And in python I'm trying to get all new messages (Python 2.6.5rc2). First, getting "Maildir" works:

```
>>> import mailbox
>>> md = mailbox.Maildir('/home/foo/Maildir')
>>> md.iterkeys().next()
'1269924477.Vfc01I4249fM708004.foo'
```

But how do I access "Maildir/new"? This does not work:

```
>>> md = mailbox.Maildir('/home/foo/Maildir/new')
>>> md.iterkeys().next()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/mailbox.py", line 346, in iterkeys
    self._refresh()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/mailbox.py", line 467, in _refresh
    for entry in os.listdir(subdir_path):
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/foo/Maildir/new/new'
>>>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folder `/home/foo/Maildir/new` is not a Maildir, it is *part* of the maildir. If you want to use `mailbox.Maildir`, you need to ignore the subdirectories and files which are part of the spec. Otherwise, you will not be treating it as a Maildir at all.

The Maildir module *should* read messages from `new` and `cur`, and may optionally move messages from `new` to `cur` when you `close()` or `flush()`. To know how this implementation does it, you will have to look at the code.

References:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maildir
- http://docs.python.org/library/mailbox.html#maildir